# Solution of using Function and For Loop for list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop

I have a datafame:-

```
    symbol  date    net_revenue gross_profit    net_income_common   total_asset
0   XLNX    30/9/2020   766535000   541719000   193816000   5575931000
1   CDSN    30/6/2020   726673000   493873000   93836000    5444763000
2   SNPS    31/3/2020   756169000   528435100   162257000   4693334000
3   KEYS    31/12/2019  723499000   483478000   162012000   4951222000
4   ANSS    30/9/2019   833366000   540260000   226993000   5019898000
```

I normally run these scripts for each row:

```
cdns = df[df['symbol'] == 'CDNS']
snps = df[df['symbol'] == 'SNPS']
keys = df[df['symbol'] == 'KEYS']
anss = df[df['symbol'] == 'ANSS']
xlnx = df[df['symbol'] == 'XLNX']

xlnx[['net_revenue','net_income_common', 'gross_profit', 'total_asset']] /= 1000
xlnx['date'] = pd.to_datetime(tick['date'])
xlnx.sort_values(['date'], ascending = True, inplace = True)
xlnx.set_index('date', inplace=True)

snps[['net_revenue','net_income_common', 'gross_profit', 'total_asset']] /= 1000
snps['date'] = pd.to_datetime(snps['date'])
snps.sort_values(['date'], ascending = True, inplace = True)
snps.set_index('date', inplace=True)
```

I want to use function and For loop method to run these script but it returns an TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not list. May I know why is the problem?

```
def multi(tick):
   tick[['net_revenue','net_income_common', 'gross_profit', 'total_asset']] /= 1000
   tick['date'] = pd.to_datetime(tick['date'])
   tick.sort_values(['date'], ascending = True, inplace = True)
   tick.set_index('date', inplace=True)
   return tick

list_ = ['xlnx','cdsn', 'snps', 'keys', 'anss']
for s in list_:
    ouput = multi(s)
```

Comment: in the first example `xlnx` is a dataframe,  in the second example `tick` is a list of strings.  They do not work the same way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're sending a list of strings, I think you wanted to send a list of dataframes like this:

```
cdns = df[df['symbol'] == 'CDNS']
snps = df[df['symbol'] == 'SNPS']
keys = df[df['symbol'] == 'KEYS']
anss = df[df['symbol'] == 'ANSS']
xlnx = df[df['symbol'] == 'XLNX']

list_ = [xlnx, cdsn, snps, keys, anss]
for s in list_:
    ouput = multi(s)
```

Comment: oh..i see. I have to send a list of dataframe instead of a list of string. Thank you very much.